# The spellchecking window partially covers the slide in Google Drive Presentations

Tags: google-drive, user-interface, google-slides

The spellchecking window partially covers the slide. This sometimes leads to situations when the word being corrected is occluded by the spellcheck window. The window is fixed and cannot be moved away.

[image]

This would be solved if I could move the slide to the left. I have a widescreen monitor so there is enough space to do that.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @OnenOnlyWalter "How can I solve my problem that the stupid floating spellchecking window covers the slide and I cannot see what is under it?"

Comment: In the Help menu there's a command to "Report an Issue". (Most Google services have this feature.) I recommend using it to report problems like this. (I just reported this one, but you can also report it and provide more info.)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by an over-sized browser setting. Try pressing the following short cut:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (command & zero) : To reset to original/default setting.

If this doesn't work or if you are not satisfied by the result, try:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (command & minus symbol): to decrease, or
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (command & plus symbol): to increase the size

PS: to be precise, this setting changes the font size of the browser.

PS2: if you use a Windows Machine, just substitute the <kbd>⌘</kbd> with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

PS3: to have this problem solved completely, you should Report it to Google. Go to Help > Report an Issue

Comment: Zooming out the page back then made it actually better since it made the overlap smaller. I tried it now and strangely it is the other way around, zooming IN decreases the overlap, which is now actually pretty tiny to start with, and therefore a non-issue. I suspect Google must have updated the app somehow… Anyways, problem sold. Thanks. I will give you the bounty, but I will not accept it as an answer since the zoom was not a cause of anything. And, I do not use Mac, so your keyboard shortcuts look confusing to me ;P

Comment: Well, I edited my post. You should report it to Google to have your problem solved. There's no other way. No problem for the not accepted answer, the bounty is cool too :p

Comment: It is solved. As I said "[…] the overlap, which is now actually pretty tiny to start with, and therefore a non-issue." Problem sold is a typo, I meant to say Problem solved.